# Cannot access hdfs remotely

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have hdfs (namenode, secodnarynamenode and datanode) running one a single machine. I am able to execute hdfs operations like 'put' when running them from the same machine, but it doesn’t work remotely, although other operations like 'ls' work fine.

I think my remote hdfs client is able to connect to namenode, but not datanode.
Namenode web console shows that there is one datanode running on localhost and this is probably the problem - it should be bound to the ip adress so that my htfs client can reach it.
I have tried to change datanode related properties:

```
  <property>
<name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
<value>192.168.1.128:50010</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
<value>192.168.1.128:50075</value>
</property>
 <property>
<name>dfs.datanode.ipc.address</name>
<value>192.168.1.128:50020</value>
</property>
```

but it didn't help. Interestingly I can access datanode UI using 192.168.1.128:50075, and there is shows that datanode runs on 192.168.1.128:50075, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Port 50075 is for `dfs.datanode.http.address`; there is also one for `dfs.datanode.address` (The datanode server address and port for data transfer), default is 50010, see [hdfs-default.xml reference](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml).

Please check if it is the port that is being listened to and whether it is accessible.

Your guessing about trouble with datanode looks correct: `ls` operation is served by namenode alone; for a `put` you need to connect to a datanode directly.

Comment: UPD: Just re-read the config provided; 50010 is definitely listened to; so need to check accessibility only.

Comment: I created a small app that reads files from hdfs, while debugging I can see 'localhost' returned from namenode as the datanode adress

Comment: Interesting, can you share a bit of that log? Also, how does 192.168.1.128 resolve at the node itself?